# Format Custom DateTime for Entire Column

Tags: python, excel, pandas, datetime

I'm looking to concatenate a bunch of csv files in the same directory that this code is ran in. I need the entire 'Date Time' column of these sheets to be in the format '**m/d/yyyy h:mm:ss.0**' and I believe I just about have it.

Here is my current code (the format changing is at the very bottom):

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import glob

# returns all data after header in panda DataFrame
def skip_to(fle, line):
    if os.stat(fle).st_size == 0:
        raise ValueError("File is empty")
    with open(fle, 'r') as f:
        if check(fle, line):
            pos = 0
            cur_line = f.readline()

            while not cur_line.startswith(line):
                pos = f.tell()
                # add current line to header dataframe
                cur_line = f.readline()
            f.seek(pos)
            
            return pd.read_csv(f, parse_dates=[line], na_values=['Unknown'])
        else:
            return ""

def check(myfile, myline):
    with open(myfile, 'r') as f:
        datafile = f.readlines()
    for line in datafile:
        if myline in line:
            return True
    return False  # finished the search without finding

# getting all csv files for concatenation
dir = os.getcwd()
files = [fn for fn in glob.glob(dir + '\**\\' + 'cdlog*.csv', recursive=True)]

df = pd.DataFrame()

for file in files:
    if file.endswith('.csv'):
        dp_data = skip_to(file, "Date Time")
        
        if type(dp_data) != str:
            dp_data.drop(0, axis=0, inplace=True)

        df = pd.concat([df, dp_data], ignore_index=True, axis=0)

df['Date Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date Time'])
df['Date Time'] = df['Date Time'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.0')

print(df['Date Time'])

# export to .csv
df.to_csv("test_output.csv")
```

With the print statement, I can see that it has it in the exact format that I'm looking for. When I check the newly created file, it is setting the format to '**mm:ss.0**' instead. If I remove the '.0' from the end of the formatting, it sets it correctly in the new sheet, but it's only recording up to the minutes - it completely cuts off the seconds and I can't figure out why.

Example with having the '.0' at the end of the formatting:

[image: csv_example1]

Example without the '.0' at the end of the formatting:

[image: csv_example2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pd.to_datetime()` is outputting a [datetime object](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), with witch you can work (to filter, to select ranges and so). If you want just a string formatted field, maybe you can apply [`dt.strftime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) on the datetime object.

Example, once you got a datetime column by `pd.to_datetime()` you can apply:

```
df['Date Time'] = df['Date Time'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.0')
```